# retrieve a word from an array in php

Tags: php

I made an array of data that has stored rows from my database, i need to check if the array contains a specific word from it, so i made

```
if($data_posts[0] == 'Payday') return echo 'this is a payday.';
```

But i am kinda struggling on this one since i am not an advanced PHP developer.
Could someone enlighten me and show me how could i move on this?

Also tried, but with no success.

```
if($data_posts[0] == "Payday"){ // if the array contains the word payday.
    echo'This is a payday.';
}else{ // if not
    echo'This is not a payday.';
}
```

Comment: Check out [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: What you are doing there is just checking if the first element of array is "Payday". https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php is what you need

Comment: as far as i understand in the docs the in_array() function is checking for the word in all the elements of the given array , while if i do ```if (in_array('Payday', $data_posts[0]))``` an error gets thrown and says the "second parameter expects to be an array"

Comment: You can use array_search(search element, your array).

Comment: Are you looking for an _exact_ match here, or are you trying to determine whether a longer text string _contains_ the word at some position? Both are two very different things.

Comment: `$data_posts[0]` contains what?

Comment: @04FS As you said , yes. trying to determine whether a longer text string contains the word at any position.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a string contains a specific word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word)

Comment: @04FS yes.! Thank you. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `in_array()` passing you array as parameter.
Using

`in_array('Payday', $data_posts[0])`

you are calling the function on a single object.

Try calling

`in_array('Payday', $data_posts)`

Comment: This presumes that `$data_posts` has individual words in in.